# React Native passing of props

Tags: android, properties, react-native

Having a really hard time with figuring out why I dont have access to a variable I should have access to.

I have a constructor

```
 constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         endpoint:props.url
      };
      console.log(props.url);// Prints url as intended
      console.log(this.state.endpoint);// Also prints as intended
```

}

Now you would think this would just carry over, to the componentDidMount, but it doesnt??  I thought a constructor was supposed to initiate something with state?

```
 componentDidMount(){
    fetch(this.state.endpoint).then(etc....)
    // this fails.  If I do console.log(this.state.endpoint) I get undefined.
 }
```

How do I get the endpoint to work in the fetch function??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see any reason why your code shouldn't work, but try this...

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch(this.props.url)
      .then( response => console.log(response) )
  }

}
```

Comment: Well, that worked. No idea why it should have to be like that....makes no sense. But oh well.

Comment: Outside of the constructor, you need to access `props` using `this.props`. I suspect that was the issue. Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

State should only be set on mounted components, or those components that are inserted into the dom. If you are not using state in your view, there is no guarantee on when it will update correctly. Why are you setting it as state? Just create a variable.

edit: or why not just use this.props.url inside of componentdidmount?

Comment: I actually resorted to using state, because I tried both your suggestions already.  And figured maybe I actually have to set the state of the component.  But yeah.....I did first just try this.endpoint and still didnt work